# RegExp to match visible non-letter characters before line break

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am working on a vbs regexp that will detect a tag which contains text and a CRLF character before closing tag.

I am currently using `\w+[:;?!.,""\)\]-~]*(\s)*(\r\n\s*)(<\/.*>)`

Looking from the end of the expression, I am matching any closing tag, CRLF plus optionally blank spaces, an optional spaces before CRLF and it should optionally match any other visible non-letter character which occurs after any word.

This is to match things like

```
myword! CRLF</tag>
mywordCRLF</tag>
myword    CRLF</tag>
myword...CRLF     </tag>
```

etc.

However, I do not want to match below, as I need to detect tags containing TEXT and linebreaks.

```
</otherclosingtag>   CRLF </tag>
```

I am concerned about the `\w+[:;?!.,""\)\]-~]*` bit as it doesn't look right to me, as I would need to insert quite a large number of characters here.

I tried replacing it with \S, \W but they all seem to match CRLF characters as well.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I used:

`\w+[^\r\n<>]*(\r\n\s*)(<\/.*>)`

It matches a word (so not ) then anything that is not the CR, LF or > (so it doesn't match `openingtag> CRLF</closingtag>`)

This is a modified version of what M42 has proposed, I had added <> to make sure we won't match a tag.

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

How about using non-greedy modifier:

```
\w+\W*?\r\n\s*(<\/.*>)
```

or

```
\w+[^\r\n]*\r\n\s*(<\/.*>)
```

Comment: Sadly, these match things like `<footnotes>CRLF</footnotes>` - I will try to modify it so that it doesn't match other tags...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^.*[\n\t\s]*</.*>$ --> BAD

^.*[\r\n\t\s]*</.*>$
```

Comment: Well, in this form this does not match anything:)
Why did you replace my `(\r\n\s*)` with `[\n\t\s]*`? My solution matched what it had to, i.e. one CRLF plus optional space, whereas yours matches any of the \n, \t or \s whether is occurs or not?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was wrong. I'll forget `\r`. 
`^.*[\r\n\t\s]*</.*>$`

Comment: Maybe you are hopeless at explaining things. Maybe you should look at logs in your eyes rather than specks in others.

Comment: `[\r\n\t\s]*` means `\r` or `\n` or `\t` or `\s` would be in line zero or more times.

Comment: @David Excuse me? I'm not sure I understand:)

Comment: When people offer help you don't spew at them. If it's wrong you appreciate the effort anyway. Consider using string functions rather than regexp.

Comment: Oh, I did appreciate the effor. My questions were not 'spewing' nor looking at specks in others eyes! The thing is that I am a beginner, so I was genuinely looking for the answer why - I had assumed it is a more optimal solution than mine and I wanted to ask why. Not being rude:)